Crop package: put info at the bottom?
The crop package has an option (info) which puts document information (file name, year, time, page number) on the top margin. See for example this book. What is the correct way to move the info to the bottom margin instead?
It looks OK if I replace the 4 in \dimen@4pt (see the code below) with a huge negative number, but there should be a "proper" method instead. Here is the relevant part from crop.sty:
\newcommand*\CROP@@info{{
    \global\advance\CROP@index\@ne
    \def\x{\discretionary{}{}{\hbox{\kern.5em---\kern.5em}}}%
    \advance\paperwidth-20\p@
    \dimen@4pt                     %<--- mentioned above
    \ifx\CROP@pagecolor\@empty
    \else
        \advance\dimen@\CROP@overlap
    \fi
    \hb@xt@\z@{%
        \hss
        \vbox to\z@{%
            \centering
            \hsize\paperwidth
            \vss
            \normalfont
            \normalsize
            \expandafter\csname\CROP@font\endcsname{%
                ``\jobname''\x
                \the\year/\the\month/\the\day\x
                \CROP@time\x
                page\kern.5em\thepage\x
                \#\the\CROP@index
                \strut
            }%
            \vskip\dimen@
        }%
        \hss
    }%
}}%


\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[cam,a4,center]{crop}

\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\CROP@@info}{\dimen@4pt}{\dimen@-20pt}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\CROP@marks}{\CROP@@@info}{}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\CROP@marks}{\CROP@loedge}{\CROP@@@info\CROP@loedge}{}{}
\let\CROP@@@marks\CROP@marks
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}


